# 独自スキーマURLを開く chrome.tab.create のコールバックが呼び出されない

Tags: firefox-webextension

#### やりたいこと

WebExtensionsのchrome.tab.createに独自プロトコルのURLを渡してタブを作成した後、OSが独自プロトコルに対応したアプリを起動する。

その後、不必要なタブを削除したい。

#### 問題

chrome.tab.create の第二引数に渡したコールバックメソッドが呼び出されない。

#### サンプルコード

```
/** background.js **/

function OpenNiconicoProtocol(niocnicoUrl = "niconico://sm9")
{
    chrome.tabs.create({url: niocnicoUrl, active:false}, OnTabCreated);
}

function OnTabCreated(tabInfo)
{
    console.log("tab id " + tabInfo.id);
    chrome.tabs.remove(tabInfo.id, () => 
    {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            console.log("failed: " + chrome.runtime.lastError);
        } else {
            console.log("removed tab");
        }
    });

}
```

独自プロトコルのURLではtabs.createのコールバックを受けられないのでしょうか？

manifest.jsonを含めたソースコード
https://gist.github.com/tor4kichi/5ea925832be5887a873ac8e7c8394ba5

テスト環境
Windows 10 AU適用済み
Firefox Developer Edition 51.0a2 (2016-10-27) (32-bit)

Answer (score 2):

自己解決しました。

### 原因

カスタムURIスキーマの場合、chrome.tabs.createの第二引数に渡されるコールバックは呼び出されません。（これがバグか仕様なのかは調べがつきませんでした。）

### 回避方法

カスタムURIスキーマを指定して作成したタブを、chrome.tabs.queryで取得して手動で閉じるようにします。

注意点として、カスタムURIスキーマにhost要素が含まれない場合、chrome.tabs.query( {url: urlPattern} ) のurlPatternの判定で invalid pattern の判定がされる場合があります。

### サンプルコード

```
    function OpenNiconicoProtocol(niocnicoUrl)
    {
        chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true }, function (maybeCurrentTab) {
            var currentTab = maybeCurrentTab[0];

            // 新しいタブとして開く
            chrome.tabs.create({url: niocnicoUrl, active:false});

            // カスタムスキームURLは tabs.create のコールバックが呼ばれない
            // 少ししてから不要なタブを閉じる処理を実行する
            setTimeout(function() {
                // queryに 渡す url がカスタムスキームかつ
                // host部分がないURLパターンの場合
                // invalid patternとなり対応していない
                // すべてのタブを取得して不要なタブを逐次判断する形で回避する 
                chrome.tabs.query( {}, (tabs) => 
                {
                        if (tabs && tabs.length)
                        {
                            for (var tabIndex in tabs)
                            {
                                var tab = tabs[tabIndex];
                                var isRemoveTarget = false;
                                if (tab.url && isNiconicoSchemeUrl(tab.url))
                                {
                                    isRemoveTarget = true;
                                }
                                else if (currentTab.index < tabIndex)
                                {
                                    // httpとしてレンダリングが実行されてないページは
                                    // tab.urlがabout:blankのままっぽい (firefoxで確認)
                                    // 現在のタブより新しく開いたっぽい空ページタブを対象として判断
                                    if (tab.url && tab.url == "about:blank")
                                    {
                                        isRemoveTarget = true;
                                    }
                                }
                                
                                if (isRemoveTarget)
                                {
                                    chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id, () => 
                                    {
                                        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
                                            console.log("failed: " + chrome.runtime.lastError);
                                        } else {
                                            console.log("removed tab");
                                        }
                                    });
                                }                               
                            }
                        }
                });
            }, 1000);
        });
        
    }
```

**参考**

Chrome拡張機能から外部プログラムでリンクを開く前にタブを閉じるには（英語）
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18564750/chrome-extension-close-tab-that-opened-an-external-program-before

chrome.tabs.query
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query

url pattern
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns